# How can I write group sql with linq

Tags: linq

I have a sql like below:

```
select catalog,queryname,count(*) from table group by catalog,queryname
```

Now how can I write it in linq and get the count?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var g =
    from record in table
    group record by new
    {
        record.catalog, record.queryname
    } into mygroup
    select new 
    {
        catalog = key.catalog,
        queryname = key.queryname
        count = myGroup.Count()
    };
```